# External libraries, MPI, Hdf5 errors

Tags: cygwin, hdf5, zlib, cactus

I am trying to run a module in cactus cygwin with carpet driver. when i use external library i get following type of error.

```
Running configuration script for thorn MPI:
MPI selected, but MPI_DIR is not set. Computing settings...
Installing MPI into /home/hp/cactus/configs/backtrace/scratch/external/MPI
MPI was manually configured.
Finished running configuration script for thorn MPI.

------------------------------------------------------
Warnings were generated during execution of the CST
------------------------------------------------------


CST error in /home/hp/cactus/lib/sbin/ImpParamConsistency.pl (at 38)
  -> Thorn 'Carpet' SHARES from non-existing implementation 'INITBASE'




    CST error in /home/hp/cactus/lib/sbin/create_c_stuff.pl (at 140)
      -> Unknown parameter type '' for parameter 'initial_data_setup_method'

    ------------------------------------------------------

    make[1]: *** [/home/hp/cactus/lib/make/make.configuration:215: /home/hp/cactus/configs/backtrace/config-data/make.thornlist] Error 1
    make: *** [Makefile:259: backtrace] Error 2
```

Comment: This does not look like a cygwin problem.

Comment: For what I see Cactus was never recently tested on Cygwin as they are mentioning Cygwin 1.3.10 as most recent and the Thorn configuration seems a bit unusal and arcane. https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2002/msg00063.html